# how to use java 8 stream and lambda to flatMap a groupingBy result

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I have a object with contains a list of other objects and I want to return a flatmap of the contained objects mapped by some property of the container. Any one if is it possible using stream and lambdas only?

```
public class Selling{
   String clientName;
   double total;
   List<Product> products;
}

public class Product{
   String name;
   String value;
}
```

Lets supose a list of operations:

```
List<Selling> operations = new ArrayList<>();

operations.stream()
     .filter(s -> s.getTotal > 10)
     .collect(groupingBy(Selling::getClientName, mapping(Selling::getProducts, toList());
```

The result would be of kind

```
Map<String, List<List<Product>>>
```

but i would like to flatten it like

```
Map<String, List<Product>>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
Map<String, List<Product>> res = operations.parallelStream().filter(s -> s.getTotal() > 10)
    .collect(groupingBy(Selling::getClientName, mapping(Selling::getProducts,
        Collector.of(ArrayList::new, List::addAll, (x, y) -> {
            x.addAll(y);
            return x;
        }))));
```

Comment: Don’t use `reduce` or `Collectors.reducing` when you modify the incoming values of the function! You may use `Collector.of(ArrayList::new, List::addAll, (x, y) -> { x.addAll(y); return x; })` instead. As a bonus of obeying the contract, that can work in parallel.

Comment: Good point, updated the code in line with your comment to make it save when used with parallelStream.

Answer (score 10):

In JDK9 there's new standard collector called [`flatMapping`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/dev/jdk/file/ec06a1714c4d/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/stream/Collectors.java#l439) which can be implemented in the following way:

```
public static <T, U, A, R>
Collector<T, ?, R> flatMapping(Function<? super T, ? extends Stream<? extends U>> mapper,
                               Collector<? super U, A, R> downstream) {
    BiConsumer<A, ? super U> downstreamAccumulator = downstream.accumulator();
    return Collector.of(downstream.supplier(),
            (r, t) -> {
                try (Stream<? extends U> result = mapper.apply(t)) {
                    if (result != null)
                        result.sequential().forEach(u -> downstreamAccumulator.accept(r, u));
                }
            },
            downstream.combiner(), downstream.finisher(),
            downstream.characteristics().toArray(new Collector.Characteristics[0]));
}
```

You can add it to your project and use like this:

```
operations.stream()
   .filter(s -> s.getTotal() > 10)
   .collect(groupingBy(Selling::getClientName, 
              flatMapping(s -> s.getProducts().stream(), toList())));
```

Comment: Is it included in some JSR?

Comment: @Madis, no. Simple API changes like adding one new method usually bypass JSR/JEP processes. Of course it has [an issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8071600) in OpenJDK bug-tracker (issue ID is obligatory for every feature).