# Grouping by and map value

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to do grouping by (to map) and then transform list of values to different list.

I have List of DistrictDocuments:

```
List<DistrictDocument> docs = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then I'm streaming over it and grouping it by city:

```
Map<String, List<DistrictDocument>> collect = docs.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(DistrictDocument::getCity));
```

I also have a method which takes DistrictDocument and creates Slugable out of it:

```
private Fizz createFizz(DistrictDocument doc) {
    return new Fizz().name(doc.getName()).fizz(doc.getFizz());
}
```

Is there a way to put that method into my stream above so I get `Map<String, List<Fizz>>` ?
I tried adding 2nd argument to groupingBy but couldn't find a proper way and been always getting compilation errors.

Edit:
What if my createFizz returns `List<Fizz>` ? Is there an option to flat this list in Collectors.mapping becasue I still want to have `Map<String, List<Fizz>>` instead of `Map<String, List<List<Fizz>>>`

Answer (score 132, accepted):

You need to chain a `Collectors.mapping()` collector to the `Collectors.groupingBy()` collector:

```
Map<String, List<Fizz>> collect =
    docs.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(DistrictDocument::getCity,
                 Collectors.mapping(d->createFizz(d),Collectors.toList())));
```

If `createFizz(d)` would return a `List<Fizz`, you can flatten it using Java 9's `Collectors.flatMapping`:

```
Map<String, List<Fizz>> collect =
    docs.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(DistrictDocument::getCity,
                 Collectors.flatMapping(d->createFizz(d).stream(),Collectors.toList())));
```

If you can't use Java 9, perhaps using `Collectors.toMap` will help:

```
Map<String, List<Fizz>> collect =
    docs.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(DistrictDocument::getCity,
                                  d->createFizz(d),
                                  (l1,l2)->{l1.addAll(l2);return l1;}));
```

Comment: `d->createFizz(d)` You can use a method reference for this. Admittedly we don't know the class.

Comment: @Michael yes, not knowing the class was the main reason I didn't use a method reference.

Comment: Could you check my edit? Unfortunately createFizz has to return List<Fizz> and I can't seem to find a way to flat out this list.

Comment: @doublemc I believe java 9 has Collectors.flatMapping, so you can write `Collectors.flatMapping(d->createFizz(d).stream(),Collectors.toList())))`;

Comment: What if I can only use up to java 8? Any option to do that?

Comment: @doublemc You can use `Collectors.toMap` instead of `groupingBy`.

Comment: If you are on java 8, you can use the `flatMapping` [backport from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32254323/1876620). You can place that helper method in any utility class.

Comment: Your last variant relies on `createFizz` to return new, mutable lists.

Answer (score 10):

In case you'd like to do a doubly nested grouping:

Let's say you have a collection of `EducationData` objects that contain School name, teacher name, and student name. But you want a nested map that looks like :

#### What you have

```
class EducationData {
     String school;
     String teacher;
     String student;

     // getters setters ...
}
```

#### What you want

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> desiredMapOfMpas ...

// which would look like this :

"East High School" : {
     "Ms. Jackson" : ["Derek Shepherd", "Meredith Grey", ...],
     "Mr. Teresa" : ["Eleanor Shellstrop", "Jason Mendoza", ...],
     ....
}
```

#### How to Get There

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

public doubleNestedGroup(List<EducationData> educations) {
     Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> nestedMap = educations.stream()
        .collect(
             groupingBy(
                  EducationData::getSchool,
                  groupingBy(
                       EducationData::getTeacher,
                       mapping(
                            EducationData::getStudent,
                            toList()
                       )
                  )
              )
        );
}
```